# How do I get data from Webuntis API?

Tags: javascript, python, google-calendar-api

I have a problem. I want to use Webuntis API and put the dates from the exam in the Google Calendar. For now I want to learn how to use the Webuntis API but I get just an Error:

> Error: Failed to login. {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"Awesome","error":{"message":"bad credentials","code":-8504}}

I tried in JavaScript and in Python, and in both of them is the same error.

JavaScript:

```
const { WebUntis } = require('webuntis');

// Erstelle eine asynchrone Funktion, um 'await' verwenden zu können.
async function main() {
  const untis = new WebUntis('BK-Beckum', 'name', 'Password', 'tritone.webuntis.com');
  await untis.login();

  const timetable = await untis.getStudents();
  console.log(timetable);

  // Weitere asynchrone Aufrufe oder Operationen können hier stattfinden.
  await untis.logout()
}

// Rufe die asynchrone Funktion auf.
main();
```

Python:

```
import webuntis

s = webuntis.Session(
    username="EngelhCar",
    password="Password",
    server = "tritone.webuntis.com",
    school = "BK-Beckum",
    useragent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0"
    )

s.login()
for klass in s.klassen():
    print(klass.name)
s.logout()
```

I tried different URL's and different schoolname's. I uninstalled the webuntis and installed it again. I tried other functions or parameter but then I got other error's.The password and username are right too, I just edit the password for this post.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, username and password are correct.
Server and school look right.
Just change useragent to useragent = "useragent".
Then it should work.

Comment: It doesn't work. But now i got a different error after I tried other things. I get a sessionID but the error is saying that the authentication went wrong

Answer (score 0):

Postman request for me works with:

```
GET https://xxx.webuntis.com/WebUntis/jsonrpc.do?school={schoolname (url encoded)}
```

Body:

```
Raw / JSON

{
    "id": 2,
    "method": "authenticate",
    "params": {
       "user": "",
       "password": "",
       "client": "CLIENT",
    },
    "jsonrpc": "2.0"
}
```

When using any code api call make sure to stringify it, it cannot be sent as an json object `{ \\"id\\": \\"2\\", ...}`.
There is a PDF [Doc](https://untis-sr.ch/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/2018-09-20-WebUntis_JSON_RPC_API.pdf) which I used, but many things might be outdated.

Comment: Thanks, i didn't know that there is a PDF which i can use.